# SMTP mail sending fail

Tags: java, ejb-2.x

I am sending mail from my local machine and got following error

```
ERROR [STDERR] javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 553 sorry, relaying denied from your location [10.105.1.186] (#5.7.1)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:848)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:323)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.elitecore.billing.utils.MailClient.send(MailClient.java:191)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.elitecore.billing.ejb.base.BillingSessionBase.sendMailToErrorAdmin(BillingSessionBase.java:935)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.elitecore.billing.ejb.base.BillingSessionBase.sendMail(BillingSessionBase.java:827)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.elitecore.billing.ejb.system.audit.session.SentEventNotificationSessionFacade.sendNotificationTo
Recepient(SentEventNotificationSessionFacade.java:1378)
19:10:50,885 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.elitecore.billing.ejb.system.audit.session.SentEventNotificationSessionFacade.sentNotification(S
entEventNotificationSessionFacade.java:809)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:6
83)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.
java:186)
19:10:50,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor
.java:72)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:84)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:341)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:148)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:111)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:191)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:122)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer.internalInvoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:331)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:709)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
19:10:50,916 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
19:10:50,932 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
19:10:50,948 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:360)
19:10:50,948 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:153)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:149)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:466)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:707)
19:10:50,963 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Can anybody explain me why this error comes ?

Comment: 553 sorry, relaying denied from your location [10.105.1.186] -- isn't that enough information? :)

Answer (score 1):

The email server is configured to send (relay) messages delivered only from certain IPs. It seems that the IP 10.105.1.186 is not accepted.